# AngularJS storing data from ng-repeat models in object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get an object like this:

```
$scope.order = {
        'client' : '24',
        'products' : [
            {'id': '23', 'format' : 'box', 'units': '3'},
            {'id': '33', 'format' : 'can', 'units': '24'},
            {'id': '11', 'format' : 'box', 'units': '4'}
        ]
    }
```

having the next controller

```
 (function(){  
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        app.controller('Controller', function($scope){
            //data from service
            var items = [
              {'id':1, 'name': 'redItem'},
              {'id':2, 'name': 'blueItem'},
              {'id':3, 'name': 'yellowItem'},
              {'id':4, 'name': 'greenItem'},
            ];

            $scope.products = items;

            $scope.order = {
                    'client' : '12',
            };
            $scope.order.products = {};

            $scope.show = function(productID){
                console.log($scope.order.products);
                console.log($scope.order);  
            };
        });
    })();
```

and view

```
<ul class="list">
<li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: 'name'">
    <p>
        <a ng-bind='product.name'></a>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="show()" ng-model="order.products.id[$index]" value="1" ng-true-value="{{product.id}}" ng-false-value="0">
        <input type="number" ng-model="order.products.units[$index]" min="1" ng-show="order.products.id[$index]"/>          
    </p>
</li>
```

I'm trying to update de object every time the checkbox is changed, adding the product id if checked and units of the input number but the structure I'm getting is wrong

```
$scope.order = {
    "client":"12",
    "products":{
      "id":{"0":1,"1":2,"3":4},
      "units":{"1":2,"3":1}
    }
}
```

any clues??

**EDIT:**

I forgot the plunker... [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wn5KGQ0T8GVf6O1tNR5V?p=preview)

Comment: here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wn5KGQ0T8GVf6O1tNR5V?p=preview) @itcouldevenbeaboat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
<ul class="list">
<li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: 'name'">
    <p>
        <a ng-bind='product.name'></a>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="show()" ng-model="order.products.id[$index]" value="1" ng-true-value="{{product.id}}" ng-false-value="0">
        <input type="number" ng-model="order.products.units[$index]" min="1" ng-show="order.products.id[$index]"/>          
    </p>
</li>
```

You are creating an array called id by using the model `order.products.id[$index]` and an array called units by using the model `order.products.units[$index]`. You are actually trying to access a product in the `order.products[]` array. Rather than jump through the hoop of creating a new object, I would mark the item as selected and track its units. You can then filter to just the selected products and do any desired transformation when the order is completed.

Controller:

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $filter){
    //data from service
    var items = [
      {'id':1, 'name': 'redItem'},
      {'id':2, 'name': 'blueItem'},
      {'id':3, 'name': 'yellowItem'},
      {'id':4, 'name': 'greenItem'},
    ];

    $scope.products = items;

    $scope.order = {
            'client' : '12',
    };

    $scope.show = function(productID){
        console.log($scope.order.products);
        console.log($scope.order);

        $scope.order.products = $filter('filter')($scope.products, { isSelected: true }, true);
    };
  });

})();
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <ul class="list">
          <li ng-repeat="product in products">
              <p>
                <a ng-bind='product.name'></a>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-change="show(product.id)" ng-model="product.isSelected" />
                  <input type="number" ng-model="product.units" min="1" ng-show="product.isSelected" />
              </p>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <p>{{order}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1DYsSYF6Fscxto6vykJU?p=preview

Comment: though the {{order}} in the view shows the object correctly the first time a checkbox is changed `{"client":"12","products":[{"id":1,"name":"redItem","isSelected":true}]}`, the console.log($scope.order) in the controller logs `Object {client: "12"}` and console.log($scope.order.products) got undefined @Ben Jaspers

Comment: Yes, the products array isn't defined until after that first console.log. You can just move the filter statement above the console.log statements. I updated my Plunker with that.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the ng-model and ng-show to reflect array instead of object and similarly modified the js code

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TNBZgKNDTDhiLt3yOJkB?p=preview

```
<input  type="checkbox" ng-change="show(product.id)" ng-model="order.products[$index].id" value="1" ng-true-value="{{product.id}}" ng-false-value="0">
<input type="number" ng-model="order.products[$index].units" min="1" ng-show="order.products[$index].id"/>
```

`$scope.order.products = [];`